# How to get actual size of physical memory?

Tags: x86, operating-system, cpu

I am trying to create a small operating system for x86 architecture.
In questions due memory management I have to now size of physical memory?
How can I get it using assembly or something else in protected mode?

Comment: Are you using a multiboot compatible bootloader (eg GRUB)?

Comment: @harold no, i've created my own simple boot loader that just load kernel into memory, switch to 32 bit mode and jump to kernel location.

Comment: The normal way to get the memory map is through the BIOS with e820.

Comment: The exact answer depends on whether you are using legacy BIOS, UEFI, or a multiboot boot loader; but in all cases, what you get is a list of all the regions of address space and an indication for each region whether it is reserved or contains usable memory. To get the total, you have to add them up. There’s no way to just get the total size.

Comment: You have to get the memory map from the BIOS *before* switching to protected mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337210. Although unfortunately there’s not a very complete answer there, there are some links that might be helpful.